# How can I bring a UIView's border behind a UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage

I'm new to Swift and I'm facing an issue while trying to develop a small application and I really hope someone will help me out.

Basically, I have a UIImage inside a UIView, and I want to send the UIView's border to the back *(See picture below)*

[image: border in front of image]

So, I'm giving the UIView a border, and it goes through my image. My question is:

*How do I bring the border of the UIView behind the UIImage?*

Note: I apologize if this is a repeated question, I was looking for answers for hours but couldn't find what I need.

Best regards!

Here is my code for the Image:

```
speakerImage.layer.cornerRadius = speakerImage.frame.size.width / 2;
speakerImage.clipsToBounds = true;
speakerImage.layer.zPosition = 1
```

And here is my code for the View:

```
speakerContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
speakerContentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
speakerContentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
speakerContentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
speakerContentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
speakerContentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
speakerContentView.layer.zPosition = -1
```

Comment: Please include the code you are creating the border with in your question.

Comment: Just added, thank you for reminding me. I totally forgot about the code !

Comment: @Krunal You've answered the question; there is no need to comment linking to your answer.

Comment: I think it is better to place the image view and your view that contains text under one super view, make them a sibling so that you can place the image view on top of the view.

Answer (score 3):

This may help you!!

- Move your image outside current (speakerContentView) view and set it in higher hierarchy so that it can get front position.
- Set vertical center Y of image equal to current (speakerContentView) view Y

Look at this image:

[image]

May be not a standard way but will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't care where you live, I will find you ! AND I WILL GIVE YOU A BIG HUG !!!!!!!!!!!! I spent hours to understand the problem. Tried coding it, but looks like it was way easier. Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help !!!

Comment: @Comrade Ha ha.. I hope, we'll meet :) You can accept (enable trickmark below vote counter)  this answer!

Answer (score 3):

You should add a **subview** with the same size of the superview below the image, and assign the border/shadow to it instead of its superview.

[image: view hierarchy]

Comment: YES ! I can't believe that this was the problem. I highly appreciate that you took time the help !